# Cookies preventing log out on Chrome (PassportJS & Express)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I just set up user functionality on my site today, but it seems that there's a cookie problem on Chrome preventing me from logging out when I log in as a user.

When I click the log out button, I am taken back to the home page, but I'm still logged in. I've placed some console.logs inside the /logout route and it seems they do not fire when I access the route.

If I refresh my browser cookies, I am able to log out once. If I log back in again, I will no longer be able to log out. Very strange. **If I go to any other browser (or to my phone), I can consistently log out with no problems at all.** It also works if I'm in an incognito tab on Chrome.

I've tried anything and everything in terms of code that could delete cookies (req.session.destroy(), etc.) to no avail.

Here's my code:

// Setup

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Something",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});
```

// All routes

```
app.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signup.ejs");
});

app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, newUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                req.flash("success", "You're now registered in as " + newUser.username + "!");
                res.redirect(301, "/");  
            });
        }
    })
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login.ejs");
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res) {
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.flash("success", "You have logged out!");
    res.redirect(301, "/");
});
```

//HTML (using EJS)

```
<div class="nav__user">
                    <% if (!currentUser) { %>

                        <a href="/login" class="loginButton">Login</a>
                        <a href="/signup" class="signupButton">Sign Up</a>

                    <% } else { %>

                        <p><%= currentUser.username %></p>
                        <a href="/logout">Log Out</a>

                    <% } %>
</div>
```

And, if it's any help, here's what I see in the Chrome network tab:

```
Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

x-powered-by: Express

location: /

vary: Accept

content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

content-length: 58

date: Sat, 05 Jan 2019 22:27:19 GMT

X-BACKEND: apps-proxy

Request Headers:

Provisional headers are shown

Referer: https://webdevbootcamp-osaisus.c9users.io/

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Any help is very much appreciated. No idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with cookies, actually.

Chrome will cache `HTTP 301` response codes received for HTTP GET requests (which makes sense as 301 is defined as "Moved Permanently").  This permanent-redirection data is stored in a different place than the cache which holds assets like images or scripts, and will not be discarded by commands like "empty cache and hard reload" which only apply to those assets.

There are a couple of ways to clear this data if you get Chrome into this state.  See [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects) for details, particularly the answers mentioning `chrome://net-internals` or the Chrome developer console.

There are also a couple of ways to avoid triggering this behavior.  One is to add the Cache-Control header to your response to `/logout`, as described [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91740):

> You can add cache control headers to a 301 and we'll follow them (expiration etc)

The right thing to do is to redirect using a response code other than `HTTP 301` which means "you've asked for something which is gone forever and lives over here now instead".  Opinions seem to differ here but 302 or maybe 307 might be the right choice.

Another option is to change your Express route to a `.post` from the current `.get` and write some Javascript to have your browser POST to `/logout` upon button click.  This does not require setting additional HTTP response headers on the server, but does require a little more code inside the client.

Comment: Changing to POST should really be a strong recommendation rather than an option.  It's a bad idea to have GET make any changes to state (other than access logs), and that includes the user's session state.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. Did the recommended changes and it now works. Appreciate it!